# How to place user in 3D space?

Tags: javascript, css, 3d

Is there any way to set the point of view in a CSS 3D transform? So far, I can create a virtual 3D space in html and in that space I have labels, each with an x,y,z coordinate. However, I can only seem to view this space from an outside perspective ( i.e. if I create a hollow cube, I can only see the outside ). Is there a way to set the location of the viewer in this space ( i.e. be inside the hollow cube )? I only have a bit of experience with these technologies, but I am not afraid of any math that may be involved. Additionally, I would like to avoid non-vanilla code such as Three.js. Thank you all for your considerations, and I would be more than happy to answer any clarifying questions.